I need to send more than one value to another form using formidable forms in wordpress
I have a wordpress website using formidbale forms, and I want to create entries in form B when form A is submitted. I stumbled across this code that I will paste below. I used the code snippets plugin to achieve this and it worked, but the issue is I want to send more than 1 entry to form B within the same script below, is that possible? And if so how could I achieve it?
add_action('frm_after_create_entry', 'create_entry_after_submission', 30, 2);

function create_entry_after_submission($entry_id, $form_id){
    if ( $form_id != 372 ) {//Change 372 to the ID of Form A
        return;
    }

    $form2 = '373';//Change 373 to the ID of Form B
    //Get user  
    if (!isset($_POST['frm_user_id'])){
        return;
    }
    $user = $_POST['frm_user_id'];
    //get data
    if (!isset($_POST['item_meta'][6614])){ //replace 6614 with the field ID of the Form A value
        return;
    }
    $new_value = $_POST['item_meta'][6614];
    //create entry
    FrmEntry::create(array(
        'form_id' => $form2,
        'item_key' => 'entry', //change entry to a dynamic value if you would like
        'frm_user_id' => $user,
        'item_meta' => array(
             6620 => $entry_id, //change 6620 to the ID of the field you want to populate (in Form B) with the entry ID of Form A
             6621 => $user,//change 6621 to the ID of the userID field in Form B
             6622 => $new_value,//Change 6622 to the ID of a field in Form B you want to populate with a value from Form A
        ),
    ));
}

I tried to create another script but it didnt run at the same time so instead it created 2 form entries in form b.
